# Show That The Following map of A metric Space Is an Isometry

Tags: geometry, analysis

Let the set $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the Metric: $d: \mathbb{R^2}$x$\mathbb{R^2}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(x,y) = \sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2}$ if there exists $\lambda$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that $y = \lambda x$ and $d(x,y)$ = $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}+\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$ if there there does not exist $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y = \lambda x$.

Show that any bijection $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ induces an isometry:

$F : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$

$     $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $     $\lambda x \mapsto \lambda f(x)$

With $\lambda x$ $\neq$ 0, $x \in S^1$, $\lambda > 0$ and $F(0) = 0$

I know that i have to show that $d(\lambda x, \lambda x')$ = $d(\lambda f(x), \lambda f(x')$ but I really don't know how to prove that result

Comment: Please go through what you have written and check whether it is understandable. BTW, a metric space cannot be an isometry since spaces and mappings are different things.

Comment: I have fixed some minor errors; please let me know if my fixes are not appropriate.

Comment: "Let the set... defined by ... if there exists .. such that .. if there does not exists ... such that ...? " It is absolutely not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: It's the problem my teacher gave me, I know it's not clear!

Comment: Are you sure that you have $\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2}$ and not $\sqrt{(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_1-x_2)^2}$?

Comment: Yeah it is $\sqrt{(y_1-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2}$

Comment: Note that if you have to use the first/second formula for computing $d(x,y)$ then you have to use the first/second formula for $d(f(x),f(y))$ as well. The only possible exception is when $x,y$ (or $f(x),f(y)$) are on the same line through the origin, but on different sides of the origin. Verify that for such points the two formulas produce the same result anway